# Проблемы с получением размера корневого элемента лэйаута при старте активити

Tags: android

Пустая активити, в ней только ConstraintLayout. При старте нужно определить его  высоту в пикселях. Делаю это, перекрывая onMeasere лэйаута, и считывая высоту в нём. Разметка:

```
    <com.lu.test.myapplication.MyConstraintLayout 
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">
    </com.lu.test.myapplication.MyConstraintLayout>
```

Кастомный лэйаут:

```
public class MyConstraintLayout extends ConstraintLayout {
    public MyConstraintLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        Log.d("my_log",Integer.toString(getHeight()));
    }
}
```

Активити:

```
package com.lu.test.myapplication;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

Данный способ отлично работает везде, КРОМЕ Андроид 9. На Андроид 9 я получаю 0 (проверял на четырёх разный девайсах и эмуляторе). Как сделать правильно?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В onMeasure нужно считывать не height(), а getMeasuredHeight().